# MUI Autocomplete with FreeSolo not detecting value of onInputChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using MUI's Autocomplete component with `freeSolo` so that the user may either select an option from the dropdown or input a value into the textfield. I am able to obtain the value of both: when the user selects and types in an arbitrary value.

However, it's only detecting the value `onChange`, not `onInputChange`. I need to distinguish between the value being selected from the options or entered as free text. I need to be able to prompt the user that they are submitting a unique option.

This is the basic MUI Autocomplete component:

```
export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div>
        <div>{`InputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
        <div>{`Value: '${value}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={data.map((option) => option.name)}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```